# Uploadify response value is always undefined from ASP.NET

Tags: javascript, asp.net, uploadify

I'm using Uploadify to upload some images with ASP.NET.
I use `Response.WriteFile()` in ASP.NET to return the result of the upload back to JavaScript.
As specified in the documentation I'm using `onAllComplete` event to check for response string from ASP.NET.

The problem is it that the `alert(response);` is always undefined in JavaScript.

JavaScript code as below:

```
$(document).ready(function() {
            var auth = "<% = Request.Cookies[FormsAuthentication.FormsCookieName]==null ? string.Empty : Request.Cookies[FormsAuthentication.FormsCookieName].Value %>";
            $('#btnUpdateProfileImg').uploadify({
                'uploader': '../script/uploadify/uploadify.swf',
                'script': '../uploadprofimg.aspx',
                'cancelImg': '../script/uploadify/cancel.png',
                'folder': '../script/uploadify',
                'scriptData': { 'id': $(this).attr("id"), 'token': auth },
                'onAllComplete': function(event, queueID, fileObj, response, data) {
                    alert(response); 
                }
            });
        });
```

ASP.NET code a below;

```
protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        try
        {
            string token = Request.Form["token"].ToString();
            FormsAuthenticationTicket ticket = FormsAuthentication.Decrypt(token);
            if (ticket != null)
            {
                var identity = new FormsIdentity(ticket);
                if (identity.IsAuthenticated)
                {
                    HttpPostedFile hpFile = Request.Files["ProfileImage"];      
                    string appPath = HttpContext.Current.Request.ApplicationPath;
                    string fullPath = HttpContext.Current.Request.MapPath(appPath) + @"\avatar\";
                    hpFile.SaveAs(Server.MapPath("~/" + uniqName));
                    Response.ContentType = "text/plain";
                    Response.Write("test");    
                }
            }
        }
        catch (Exception ex)
        {
            Response.Write("test");
        }
    }
```

Reason for the `FormsAuthenticationTicket` object is to pass the authentication cookie though when using the Uploadify with Firefox.

I have seen many examples where `Response.Write` returns a value back to the `onAllComplete` event.  But all I get is undefined.
I have also tried to use `Context.Response.Write`, `this.Response.Write`, `HttpContext.Current.Response.Write`.  They all return undefined.

Any help appreciated.
Thanks

Comment: When you set a breakpoint on if (identity.IsAuthenticated) is the breakpoint being hit?

Comment: I would add a 'default' response .NET code to start with to ensure the correct flow of execution. Your debugging hasn't ruled out all options yet.

Comment: Yes, the identity.IsAuthenticated returns true and the saving of image takes place.  Also the Response.Write("test"); line is actually hit before the .NET code exists.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

It seems that the onAllComplete event never fires.  This is possibly because I'm automatically uploading single files rather than multiple files.
I find that the onComplete event fires and I can use that instead.

Comment: Please post your full answer here since you have marked it as an "answer" of your post.